# iTunes Shared Library missing artist artwork

Tags: itunes, sharing, macos

When accessing an iTunes library shared over the local network, why do the usual artist images not appear? The album artwork appears just fine.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem is seen in all iTunes versions after 12.4.
It doesn't depend on a local network. Apple will not help you or anyone.

Comment: HI, and welcome to StackExchange! This doesn't seem to be an answer, and would probably be better as a comment. I know you don't have the ability to comment yet, but I've flagged this so someone can review it. See if you can get enough points to comment in the mean time! apple.stackexchange.com/unanswered is a great place to start.